# reduce the size of a js file

Tags: javascript, performance, webpack

the `js` file on my site has a size of 1.5 MB . i am assuming it could be reduced.
this file is generated by compiling many modules using `gulp version "3.9.1"` and `webpack "4.8.2"`

I have tried to minify the js file using `gulp-uglify` but the difference is very slim.

bellow is the code of my `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path'),
UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin'),
settings = require('./settings');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    App: settings.themeLocation + "scripts/app.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, settings.themeLocation + "scripts"),
    filename: "app-fin.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },


  mode: 'development'
}
```

on my `gulpfile.js` file I have this code to call `webpack`

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(callback) {
  webpack(require('./webpack.config.js'), function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.toString());
    }

    console.log(stats.toString());
    callback();
  });
});
```

my Questions :

1. does a js of 1.5 MB can cause some performance issues?
2. does `webpack` automatically minify my `js` as a result when i used `gulp-uglify` there were no impact ?
3. any suggestion on how to reduce further the size of the file

Comment: In development, most compilers will not minify down your code, rather, in production, they will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does a js of 1.5 MB can cause some performance issues?

Depending your performance target, it'll definetly have an impact. It's not only download time but also your 'time to interact' will suffer because of long javascript execution time. If you want to achieve <1s time to interactive, that file will probably loose you around 100-500ms (in good devices). Much more in slower devices.

> does webpack automatically minify my js as a result when i used gulp-uglify there were no impact ?

Webpack uses default optimizations depending on your build target (production/dev). You can achieve nice performance boost by changing your config. Please refer to here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

> any suggestion on how to reduce further the size of the file

- Divide your bundle. In a performant project, you'd like to download only the js files you'll use.
- Try to remove unused or unnecessary big node modules. Some examples: instead of moment.js you can check date-fns. You don't need whole lodash for just couple of functions, you can implement them your self or use packages such as lodash.set, lodash.get etc.
- You can take a look at google closure compiler to eliminate dead code: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler

Comment: Thanks for the details I will implement your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

*+1 to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56241045/6502003) and to expand there are various approaches you can take to reducing your bundle size.*

---

As an introduction to the cost of your JS, [Addy Osmani has one of the best intros out there](https://medium.com/@addyosmani/the-cost-of-javascript-in-2018-7d8950fbb5d4).

### Practical Methods to improve Perf:

1. Ensure when you are building for production that you set `mode: 'production'`
2. Use [Webpack bundle analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to find packages that are contributing most to bloat
3. Leverage code splitting with [dynamic imports](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import) so that only the code that is needed is loaded. Use [React Lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) + [Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#suspense) or something like [React Loadable](https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/loadable-components/)
4. Make sure you are leveraging [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) by importing modules like this: `import { module } from 'package'`
5. Research [babel plugins](https://github.com/babel/awesome-babel#optimization) that could help further optimize your bundle for size & speed

---

Before you start though, it is best practice to set some goals by **benchmarking** against competitors or other similar apps using something like [SpeedCurve](https://speedcurve.com/) or [WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/).

[image: SpeedCurve benchmark competitors]